# Make a banner fall from behind a header

Tags: javascript

I want to make this wood banner "fall" from behind the header whenever the user hovers over it.

[image]
[image]

I have searched the entire web for at least an example of how to do it. I found none. I know there is something called Google Gravity, which drops objects to the bottom of the page. Maybe that's it, only that I would like the banner to fall according to the cord's length. Now I haven't tried anything because I simply don't know how to tackle it. There is for sure some javascript going on. 
Can any of you give me a hand?

Answer (score 1):

Check out JQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).

JQuery is a javascript library which should be able to do this task easily, and which is relatively easy to understand.

For example, if your image has the id, `drop`, you could do the following:

In CSS, set the #drop selector to display:none; make it invisible:

```
#drop { display:none }
```

In JQuery, you can use the same selector to make it drop down after a certain event (a click, a countdown, a mouseover, whichever).  Here's a mouseover example for a banner, with id `banner`:

```
$('#banner').mouseover(function(){
  $('#drop').slideDown();
});
```

You can add JQuery with a script tag at the bottom of your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you want to customize it, then I would use animate() instead of slideDown().  Animate can change an element's CSS: altering `margin-top` or `top` in your situation should let you move the element whatever distance from the top of the page.